# how to initialize GLUT in a premade window

Tags: opengl, visual-c++

I was wondering if I can initialize glut in a window I made before in visual c++ , because I tried to initialize openGl using the pixel format descriptor and failed multiple times , so my question is how to initialize GLUT in a specific size in a large window 
Because I want to put some buttons and text boxes near the glut viewport

Comment: I am using the WinMain function and the WinProc function

Comment: "*I tried to initialize openGl using the pixel format descriptor and failed multiple times*" Since other people are capable of doing that (as demonstrated by the fact that GLUT works), wouldn't it make more sense to find out what you're doing wrong?

Comment: Sir , I did copy and paste a code from nehe website and window is running on white background and didn't draw anything

Comment: Also it gets me a error with multiple numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using (Free)GLUT, you have essentially given up control over the specifics of things like window creation. GLUT has no mechanism to "adopt" a window provided by the user.

So if you want to create the window yourself, you have to also have to manage it yourself, with all the OpenGL context creation stuff that entails.